# By calculating the center of mass integrals

Tags: integration

[image]

Calculate the center of mass ( CM ) of the sheet bounded by

y=(1/2) x; 
y=x;
y=0; 
x=2;
 δ(x,y)=x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the vector called center of mass is (for a two dimensional object)

$$\vec R=\frac1 M\iint_A\rho(\vec r)\vec r dxdy$$
here

$$M=\iint_A\rho(\vec r)dxdy$$

is the "mass of the area".

$A$ is given as shown below

[image]

Now,

$$M=\int_0^2\left[\int_{\frac x2}^x\ x\ dy\right]\ dx=\frac43.$$

Then,

$$\iint_A\rho(\vec r)\vec r dxdy=\int_0^2\left[\int_{\frac x2}^x x^2\ dy\right]\ dx\vec i+\int_0^2\left[\int_{\frac x2}^x xy\ dy\right] \ dx\vec j$$

because

$$\vec r=x\vec i+y\vec j.$$

So,

$$\int_0^2\left[\int_{\frac x2}^x x^2\ dy\right]\ dx=2$$

and

$$\int_0^2\left[\int_{\frac x2}^x xy\ dy\right] \ dx=\frac32.$$

Finally, the center of mass

$$\vec R=\frac34\left[2\vec i+ \frac32 \vec j\right].$$

Comment: I would stay as   M = dxdy M=∫ab[∫cd x dx] dy=4/3

Comment: @Lol! Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I would stay as M, but dxdy